# How can I install Entrust's Apple Root Certificate onto Linux (Fedora 14) platform?

Tags: linux, ssl-certificate, fedora, apple-push-notifications

I am working on setting up the ApnsPHP to communicate with Apple's Push Server. It is required to install / import Entrust Root Certificate onto the system.

So I only need to download the .cer and convert it to .pem and put it in /etc/ssl/certs ?

Do I need to set any conf file or reboot the system to make it ready for use ?

Thanks.

p.s. I am using Apache LAMPP on Fedora 14 now

Answer (score -1):

You need to consult **update-ca-certificates(2)** for exact paths, but the gist is this:

1. Copy certificate (in **.crt** form) to /usr/local/share/ca-certificates
2. Run *update-ca-certificates* with appropriate credentials.

You might need to change some entries in /etc/ca-certificates.conf, and/or change the paths for your system - however it shouldn't be much of a problem.